# How to pass is operator parameter through function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
val k = " asdfasdf "
fun test() {
    if(k is String) {
     // Do something
    }
}
```

So, how do I pass that String through the function calls
eg:

```
fun test(xxxx) {
    if(k is xxxx) {
    // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
inline fun <reified T> testType(k: Any) {
   if(k is T) {
     println("is a ${T::class.simpleName}")
   } else {
     println("is not a ${T::class.simpleName}")
   }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
test<String>("Hello") // is a String
test<String>(1) // is no String
```

[Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) some further reading.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a predicate, e.g.:

```
fun testIt(predicate: (Any?) -> Boolean) {
  if (predicate(k)) {
    println("matches!")
  } else println("nope")
}
```

and call it as follows:

```
testIt { it is String }
testIt { it is Int }
```

Or you can use a reified type:

```
inline fun <reified T> testIt() {
  when (k) {
    is T -> println("matches!")
    else -> println("nope")
  }
}
```

and call it like:

```
testIt<String>()
testIt<Int>()
```

For simplicity I kept your current variable inside the `testIt`-method... you may want to redesign that ;-)

I basically assumed a member variable as follows: `var k : Any? = null`

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities, depending on your needs.

## 1. Use `inline` and a `reified` type parameter

You can use the `reified` keyword on the type parameter in combination with an `inline` function:

```
inline fun <reified T> test(k: Any) {
    if (k is T) {
        println("k is a T!")
    }
}
```

[See the documentation on `reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

## 2. Use `KClass<T>`

If you do not want to or cannot make your function `inline` you can use a `KClass` parameter:

```
fun <T : Any> test(k: Any, type: KClass<T>) {
    if (type.isInstance(k)) {
        println("k is a T!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inline fun <reified T> isType(obj: Any): Boolean {
    return obj is T
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val test = "This is a String"
    if (isType<String>(test)) {
        println("Success")
    } else {
        println("Failure")
    }
}
```